# Have Outlook always send from same address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have MS Outlook 2016 and about 6 email accounts set up with it. Is there a way I can set one address to be the default for sending?

Currently, the sending address is whichever inbox I am viewing when I click 'New Email.' This has resulted in sending a lot of emails from the wrong address.

This is a small issue that could be solved by checking (changing) the from every time I send an email, but there has got to be a more efficient way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They finally added this feature in 2016.

Go to outlook options --> Mail --> Send Messages --> Check box "Always use the default account when composing new messages"

[image]

---

For anyone that is using Outlook 2013/2010 you have to change registry keys as follows:

In **Outlook 2013**, the key is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​15.0\​Outlook\​Options\​Mail
DWORD value: NewItemsUseDefaultSendingAccount
Value: 1

In **Outlook 2010**, edit this key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​14.0\​Outlook\​Options\​Mail
DWORD value: NewItemsUseDefaultSendingAccount
Value: 1

Comment: It's amazing it took so long for this feature to be a thing.